# Poker, ask whether or not my card is already in use

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript noob and would like to know if there's a better way to ask my script whether or not the card generated is already in use.

Right now, I'm using a bunch of **Or** operators but, there's gotta be a less redundant way to do it. If any of you could answer my question it would truly help me in the long run. Thanks

```
var cards = ['Ace of heart','Ace of club','Ace of diamond','Ace of spade',
                 'Two of heart','Two of club','Two of diamond','Two of spade',
                 'Three of heart','Three of club','Three of diamond','Three of spade',
                 'Four of heart','Four of club','Four of diamond','Four of spade',
                 'Five of heart','Five of club','Five of diamond','Five of spade'];

    // Distributed Cards //
    var pre_flop = [1];
    var flop = [2];
    var turn = [0];
    var river = [0];

    // Cards value //
    var your_card;
    var indexed_cards = [6];

    var total_card = 0;
    var deck_size = cards.length;       

    function generate_card(){

        // Assign value to first card //
        if(total_card === 0){
            your_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck_size);
            indexed_cards [total_card] = your_card;
            total_card++;
        }else{
            your_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck_size);
            // Makes sure the cards are different //
            while(1){
                if(your_card === indexed_cards [0] || your_card === indexed_cards [1] || your_card === indexed_cards [2] || your_card === indexed_cards [3] || your_card === indexed_cards [4] || your_card === indexed_cards [5] || your_card === indexed_cards [6]){
                    your_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck_size);
                }else {
                    indexed_cards [total_card] = your_card;
                    break;
                }
            }
            total_card++;           
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the trick is generating a whole deck in an array and shuffling it, just like you'd do in the real world. Since each card in the deck is unique, you eliminate the whole error condition of duplicates if you just pop cards from the shuffled array.

Comment: `var indexed_cards = [6];` I'm not sure what you think this does, but I'm guessing it doesn't do that.

Comment: I'm with @mat - You're making an array containing one element with the value `6`, where it looks like you're trying to declare an array of length 6. Otherwise I can't fathom why you'd have every poker hand contain a 6.

Comment: I see.. How do i make an array of length 6 then?

Comment: You make an array and you put six things in it. If you put another in it then it becomes an array of seven things. You don't have to allocate these up front like you do in C for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question about replacing ORs:

You can use array.indexOf(..) to find out whether something is in an array.

```
var myarray = [1, 3, 77, 12, 9];

console.log('index of 77 ' + myarray.indexOf(77));    // 2
console.log('index of 4 ' + myarray.indexOf(4))    // -1
```

indexOf returns -1 if an item isn't found, else it returns the item's position in the array. You may have also seen this method used on strings, to find the position or presence of a character in a string; same principle applies here.

Other problems with the code may be present, but you should be able to replace

```
if(your_card === indexed_cards [0] || your_card === indexed_cards [1] || your_card === indexed_cards [2] || your_card === indexed_cards [3] || your_card === indexed_cards [4] || your_card === indexed_cards [5] || your_card === indexed_cards [6]){
```

with

```
if (indexed_cards.indexOf(your_card) !== -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

That's essentially it, you could use a jquery array.contains or indexOf check if you wanted to make it look more pretty.

I'm assuming 6 is the max length of the indexed_cards array.